# Welcome message when excel opens using OpenXML in c#

Tags: c#, excel, alert, openxml-sdk

Hi I am creating an **excel** file through `Openxml 2.5 SDK` in c#. What i need to do is show a *`Welcome message`* in alert pop up.
I have used some ideas like `SheetProtection` which works when file opens but didn't get the actual solution.
Do any one have something useful. I am digging since last two days on it.

[image: There should be message when excel opens]

```
SheetProtection sheetProt = new SheetProtection()
 {
    Sheet = true,
    Objects = true,
    Scenarios = true,
    Password = "Password"
  };
 worksheetPart1.Worksheet.InsertAfter(sheetProt, worksheetPart1.Worksheet.Descendants<SheetData>().LastOrDefault());

 worksheetPart1.Worksheet.Save();
```

This is the code we use for password protection and i need which work like this.

Comment: You want Excel to show a message, when the file is opened using Excel? What about Excel-online? Can you use VBA? Is the installation of an Add-on (in Excel) allowed?

Comment: @GvS I can use C# only along with openxml and no thirdparty tool.

Comment: There is no provision in the Open Excel file format that allows displaying a "message box". The best you could do is content on the worksheet that displays when the file is opened. Or, this would need to be a xlsm (macro-enabled workbook) that includes a VBA project with something like an `Auto_Open` procedure to display a message.

Comment: @CindyMeister this dosn't sounds good to me. Thanks i will see some other option.